# Custom commercewebservices with the new extension in Hybris-Spartacus project

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We would like to use the Spartacus framework with version 2005 of Sap Commerce Cloud (Hybris).
There is a custom commercewebservices (created from ycommercewebservices)  extension that is already in use. **We don't want to touch it.**

Based on the following documentation, here are the steps for version 2005.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2005/en-US/d46d19516961438f8939718e87ed787b.html

**1) Create a new custom extension from yocc. Let's call it xxxocc.**

**xxxocc requires commercewebservices with the webcontext /occ**

**2) xxxocc should require out of the box (OOTB) cmsocc to get cms pages and components info for Spartacus.**

**cmsocc requires commercewebservices with the webcontext /occ.**

**Current custom commercewebservices has its own commercewebservices settings with the webcontext /rest.**

After creating a new extension from yocc(xxxocc), custom commercewebservices has a lot of conflicts with the new one. (commerceStockFacade, security settings, contextInformationLoader etc.)

We could resolve these issues with big efforts but after requiring cmsocc in the xxxocc extension, the same errors are going to happen again because the cmsocc has also its own commercewebservices, and resolving issues for the cmsocc extension is not possible without making it a custom extension like xxxcmsocc.

**What should be the best approach to use the current commercewebservices along with the new extension in a project?**

Answer (score 0):

You just have to install occaddon in your custom ws extension,
First I recommend to you, create your customwebservices extensions from **ycommercewebservices** template, with `ant modulegen` tool

Second install occaddon to your customwebservices extension

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="cmsoccaddon" -DaddonStorefront.ycommercewebservices="customwebservices"
```

remember to list **cmsoccaddon** in your **localextensions**

Finally, execute `ant clean all` and start up your server, you should be able to see cms endpoints without conflict,

Regards.

Comment: After Installing cmsoccaddon on custom WS getting bellow error for /page. /component is working find.
While attempting the following mapping: sourceType = de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.data.PageContentSlotData sourceProperty = slotShared(boolean) destinationType = java.util.ArrayList&lt;ContentSlotWsDTO&gt; destinationProperty = 8(ContentSlotWsDTO) Error occurred: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: Encountered mapping of primitive to object (or vise-versa); sourceType=boolean, destinationType=ContentSlotWsDTO